# Can I get a trace of TypeScript statements executed in a SharePoint SPFx client web part?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

Is there a way with gulp serve to get a trace of TypeScript statements that are executed in a SPFx client application ?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what you are trying to achieve?  Are you looking for logging to the console?  Stack traces at various points in your code?

Comment: I am looking for being able to log statements that have been executed to a console.

Comment: So are you looking for a stack trace on every function call?  Logging when specific actions take place?  Take a look at this post and see if it serves your needs - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Working-with-the-Logging-API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some logging support built into the framework.  Documentation can be found here - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Working-with-the-Logging-API , and a blog post by Wictor here - http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-framework-nuggets-logging-like-a-pro